# Apache spark python two dataframe rdd map not executing in parallel

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have 40 million resume document and 1 million job titles. 
we are using dataframe for both and then cross joining both documents. 
Then we are using finaldata.rdd.map(lambda row: process_row(row)) 
the function is taking too much time. It is not executing in parallel.

```
sc = SparkContext()
    collection_file = sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:port/user/Mongo_11July")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    collection_df = sqlContext.read.json(collection_file)
    collection_df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp1")


    jobtitle_file = sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:port/user/Jobtitle_11July")


    jobtitle_df = sqlContext.read.json(jobtitle_file)
    jobtitle_df.createOrReplaceTempView("jobtitle")



    df_cases = sqlContext.sql("SELECT _id,HTMLtext FROM temp1 ")
    df_job_titles = sqlContext.sql("SELECT distinct(Name) FROM jobtitle")



    schema = StructType([
        StructField("_id", StructType([StructField("$oid",StringType(),True)]), True),
        StructField("HTMLtext", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("Tags_Add", ArrayType(StringType()), True)])   

    finaldata = df_cases.crossJoin(df_job_titles) 
    new_rdd = finaldata.rdd.map(lambda row: process_row(row)) 
    new_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(new_rdd,schema) 
    final_new_df = new_df.groupBy("_id").agg(collect_list("Tags_Add").alias("Tags_Add"))
    flattenUdf = F.udf(fudf, ArrayType(StringType()))
    outputdataframe=final_new_df.select("_id", flattenUdf("Tags_Add").alias("Tags_Add"))
```

Comment: Are you executing this on a multi-node cluster, or is this in a local execution mode? Also, can you share insights on yor `process_row()` function? If it is a python-native operation, it should be limited to sequential execution, since it is essentially limited by Python's single-threaded property.

Comment: We are executing on multinode cluster. in process row we have written custom code to find xpath of word in document . using third party library.

Comment: Have you tried changing the replication size of your HDFS file? Depending on how big your total file size is, that might help the process. But unles you manage to "parallelize" your process_row() function, I fear there is not much speed-up to be gained here...